# Passing JS array as a List<> to Spring MVC controller

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, post, model-view-controller

I'm developing the front end to my webapp using ReactJs. Here, I make an API POST passing in a array of objects.

The objects are created in an event handler, as follows:

```
eventHandler(id1, id2, e) {
    let payload = this.state.payload;
    let changedItem= {
        changeTo: e,
        id1: id1,
        id2: id2
    };

    let res = [];
    payload.forEach(item=> {
        if (item.id1 !== id1
            || item.id2 !== id2) {
            res.push(control);
        }
    });
    res.push(changedItem);

    this.setState({
        payload: res
    });
}
```

I have verified this works by printing the array after this. Next, I make a POST call, passing in the array:

```
onClick() {

    let changedControls = (this.state.payload);

    updateControls(changedControls).then(() => {
        this.setState({
            payload: []
        });
    }).catch((error) => {
         console.log(error);
    })
}
```

The API call is defined in a separate file, as:

```
export const updateControls = (changedControls) => {
let uri = '/api/update-controls';
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios.post(uri, changedControls).then(response => {
        if (response != null) {
            resolve(response.data)
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err.response.data);
    })
})
```

};

Ideally, the next step would have been my Java controller being called, defined as:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update-controls", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void updateControls(@RequestParam(value = "updatedControls") List<ControlsUpdate> updatedControls) throws Exception {
    initServiceClientRest();
    String user = getUserId();

    ResponseEntity responseEntity = serviceClientRest.update(updatedControls, user);

    if (responseEntity != null) {
        if (responseEntity.getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.OK) {
            throwErrorMessages(responseEntity);
        }
    }
}
```

I believe this is where the error lies. I get a 400 error, saying: Required List parameter 'updatedControls' is not present'.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Sorry about the typo in the API POST call! But that wasn't the issue, just a typo I made while copying in the code

EDIT2:

Error:

```
feign.FeignException$InternalServerError: status 500 reading serviceClientRest#updateAccessControls(List,String)
at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:114) ~[feign-core-10.2.3.jar:na]
at feign.FeignException.errorStatus(FeignException.java:86) ~[feign-core-10.2.3.jar:na]
at feign.codec.ErrorDecoder$Default.decode(ErrorDecoder.java:93) ~[feign-core-10.2.3.jar:na]
at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:149) ~[feign-core-10.2.3.jar:na]
at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:78) ~[feign-core-10.2.3.jar:na]
at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103) ~[feign-core-10.2.3.jar:na]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy155.updateAccessControls(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at ScoringConfigController.updateControls(ScoringConfigController.java:135) ~[main/:na]
```

Comment: @arcy tagged it with Java because I believe the problem had to do with my Java controller code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sending your array as a request body right? You have to use `@RequestBody` instead of `@RequestParam`

```
public void updateControls(@RequestBody List<ControlsUpdate> updatedControls) throws Exception {...}
```

`@RequestParam` is used for URL query strings

Comment: I had tried @RequestBody before, which came back with a different error if I am remembering right. Trying it again now to verify

Comment: Just ran it again, came back with "500 error trying to read serviceClientRest#updateAccessControls(List,String)"

Comment: Can you update your post printing the java exception related to this?

Comment: @fragElephant Hard to tell, I'm not familiar with Feign. I suggest you to open a new post (specifiying Java / Spring / Feign) describing this particular error. Or you can try some debugging starting into `updateControls` method. You'll be able to check if your `List<ControlsUpdate>` is correctly unserialized and where the problem is located

Comment: @fragElephant Did you make sure Your axios call is passing Your data in expected structure?

Comment: Accepting this as the answer. Changing to @RequestBody solved this specific bug. The FeignError was related to another separate issue which I just found. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.post(uri, changedControls).then(response => {
```

instead of

```
axios.post(uri, updatedControls).then(response => {
```

Comment: Sorry about that, but not the issue. Updated the question. Thanks!